# Random erasing at multiple random regions of image

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch

I want to implement a custom random erasing function.

This function would take an input image and a percentage to mask, but would then mask between 1 and 4 random rectangles whose total area adds up to the mask percentage.

For example, say my image is 100*100 pixels, and my mask percent is 15% so I randomly choose to create 3 rectangles with random shapes such that their combined area sums up to 100*100*0.15 pixels.

so far i managed to write the code that decides upon the width and height and amount of rectangles, but i struggle with the part that makes sure they don't mask the same spot.

```
img_c, img_h, img_w = img.shape[-3], img.shape[-2], img.shape[-1]
        area = img_h * img_w

        for _ in range(10):
            block_num = torch.randint(1,4,(1,)).item()
            block_sizes = torch.rand((block_num))
            block_sizes = torch.round((block_sizes / block_sizes.sum()) * (area * mask_percent))
            h = torch.round((torch.rand(block_num)+0.5) * block_sizes.sqrt())
            w = torch.round(block_sizes / h)

            
            xs = []
            ys = []
            if not (any(h < img_h) and any(w < img_w)):
                continue
            term = True
            while term:
                xs = [torch.randint(0, img_h - h_ + 1, size=(1, )).item() for h_ in h]
                ys = [torch.randint(0, img_w - w_ + 1, size=(1, )).item() for w_ in w]
                for iter,x in enumerate(xs):
                    if (x+h[iter]-xs)<0

#here i get all confused. should have a loop that goes over each point and checks that the location + axial size 
#doesn't go over another point. it's confusing because should i also take care  vice versa? maybe someone knows of a ready made solution? 

            return i, j, h, w, v

        # Return original image
        return 0, 0, img_h, img_w, img
```

the while loop is released once the random location generator generates locations that corresppond to the terms.

******************************edit******************************_____________

my latest attempt seems to work, but always exits the loop unsolved! is it just not a very likely set of parameters?

```
img = torch.rand(1,160,1024)
img_c, img_h, img_w = img.shape[-3], img.shape[-2], img.shape[-1]
        area = img_h * img_w

        for _ in range(100):
            block_num = torch.randint(1,3,(1,)).item()
            block_sizes = torch.rand((block_num))
            block_sizes = torch.round((block_sizes / block_sizes.sum()) * (area * 0.15))
            h = torch.round((torch.rand(block_num)+0.5) * block_sizes.sqrt()).to(dtype=torch.long)
            w = torch.round(block_sizes / h).to(dtype=torch.long)

            if (h > img_h).any() or (w > img_w).any():
                continue
            overlap1 = torch.zeros(img.shape)
            xs = [torch.randint(0, img_h - h_.item() + 1, size=(1, )).item() for h_ in h]
            ys = [torch.randint(0, img_w - w_.item() + 1, size=(1, )).item() for w_ in w]
            for iter,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(xs,ys)):
                overlap1[0,x:x+h[iter],y:y+w[iter]] += 1
            if (overlap1>1).any():
                continue
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are checking that rectangle2 doesn't overlap with rectangle1, just check their intersection area. If intersection area is greater than 0, reject rectangle2 and check next random rectangle. Repeat the process with new rectangle.

For checking intersection - use sklearn's Jaccard score (avoid reinventing the wheel). To be able to use Jaccard for comparison, the two arrays (images) should be of same size. So generate original image size equivalent masks (mask1 and mask2) from your rectangle1 and rectangle2 respectively and then calculate Jaccard of mask1 and mask2.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score

mask1 = np.array([[0, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 0]])
mask2 = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 0, 0]])

jaccard_score(mask1, mask2)
```

> 0.6666

Comment: ok, this might work.
but when considering computation expenses - isn't it way more costly to generate the image with the jaccard score than some for loop that checks whether there is an overlap?
consider this random erasing would happen everytime input is fed into a neural network

Comment: yes of course it will be expensive. If you want efficiency, you'll need to design a dynamic programming based solution.